# Finding $x$ using logs - two methods give different answers

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, quadratics

I have been presented with the following question:

$$\log_3x +\log_x3 = 2.$$

I convert $\log_x3$ to base $3$ giving:

$$\log_3x +\frac{1}{\log_3x} = 2.$$

Then allow $\log_3x = u$ giving :

$$u+\frac{1}{u}=2.$$

I then multiply by $u$ and subtract two to give

$$u^2-2u + 1 = 0.$$

From here I find $u$ using two methods.

Method $1$ - using the quadratic formula which gives me $u=1.$

Method 2 - finding 2 numbers (factors) that adds to $-2$ and multiplies to $1$, this gives me $u=-1.$

Of course I then have two different results for $x$.

Please can someone show me where I have gone wrong?

EDIT - method 2 finds factors not roots, this was my error.

Comment: $u=-1$ doesn't work in the equation $u^2-2u + 1 = 0$, so your reasoning is wrong there. In addition, you have found $u$, but you're looking for $x$. So how can you proceed?

Comment: $-1+-1=-2$ and $-1*-1=1$ ? to find $x$ i will compare $log_3x = u$

Comment: Ok, you found two number (-1 and -1) which add up to -2 and multiply together to give you 1. That gives you a factorization of your quadratic. What is that factorization? What does that tell you about the solutions of the quadratic equation?

Comment: I Cannot understand method 2 at all. Finding a number (singular) that adds to -2? Do you mean finding an m so that m+m =-2 and mxm = 1?  Why do you want to do that?  If you have such a number then $m^2-2m+1=1-(-2)+1=3$.  How does that help you?

Comment: @fleablood take a look at either the edit on the question or my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $u^2-2u+1=0$ is equivalent to 
$$
(u-1)^2 = 0
$$
which has one real solution $u=1$. So $\log_3 x = 1$ and $x=3$.

When you use method 2 (finding two numbers that add to $−2$ and multiply to give $1$) - this is where the error is. The two roots should actually add to $2$! (Recall [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas#Example).)

Answer (score 2):

In method 2 you are trying to factor the polynomial. Note that $(-1) + (-1) = -2$ and $(-1)(-1) = 2$ so we have $u^2 - 2u + 1 = (u + (-1))(u + (-1)) = (u - 1)^2$. Thus $(u - 1)^2 = 0$ so $u = 1$, which agrees with the other answer. The reason this factoring method works is because $(x + a)(x + b) = x^2 + (a + b)x + ab$.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic formula gives a root,

the other method: $u$ and $v$ in $ax^2 +bx +c$ where $u*v=a*c$ and $u+v=b$, gives a factor.

I need the root in order to find x.

Comment: You mean $uv= \frac ca$ and $u+v = \frac ba$.  And the numbers u,v where $u+v = \frac ba$ and $u*v=\frac ca$ are not the "factors" of the equations.  $x + u$ and $x+v$ are the factors of the equation.  And it's a really *bad* idea to think that factors of equations and roots of equations are two concepts.  They are intertwined.  $r$ and $s$ are the roots if and only if $x-r$ and $x-s$ are the factors.  So quite simply method 2, should be you want $u*v = \frac ca$ and $u + v = -\frac ba$ (and so $ax+bx+c = a(x-u)(x-v)$.  Finding $u+v = +\frac ba$  is ... not relevant.  It never was.